# Table caption in floatrow environment

Tags: tables, captions, floatrow

I am using  the floatrow environment to display a figure and a table side by side.
Here is my latex code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\CenterFloatBoxes
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox
{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, inner]{sc_topo.jpeg}}
{\caption{Example of figure}\label{fig:test}}
\ttabbox
{\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
A& B& C& D\\
1& 2& 2 & 3 \\
1& 2& 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
{\caption{An example of plan}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What I get is :

```
*******FIG********    *******TABLE CAPTION ********
****FIG CAPTION***    ***********TABLE ************
```

But I would like to align the captions below the figure and the table, not one above and one below :

```
*******FIG********    *******TABLE ********
****FIG CAPTION***    ***TABLE CAPTION ****
```

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! Which document class are you using? Some like the KOMA classes have this built in as a feature. Also please try to always post a complete code example, people are more likely to help if they just need to copy the code and not make guesses about your documentclass and packages!

Comment: Oh ok, Sorry . Post Updated !

Comment: Probably try `\floatsetup[table]{capposition=bottom}` in the preamble?

Comment: It does not move the caption - Still above the table. It is strange as when I try to put the capiont beside the table with "capposition=beside,
capbesideposition={bottom,right}" then the caption is correctly moved beside the table

Comment: Finally sorted the problem using minipage. Anyway, thanks for your help sir